# Cleaning up a large python class for readability and becoming more pythonic/OO

Tags: python

I have a `class` that takes in two strings  via the `__init___` method and then does a bunch of string manipulation to return numerous other strings via instance methods.  Some instance methods rely on other instance methods.  Anyways, I feel like this could be made more pythonic and OO, but I'm quite bad at more advanced OO topics, like using `@property`, `@staticmethod`, `@classmethod`, etc.

```
ACTIVE_DATASETS = active.datasets

class FileMetadata:
    def __init__(self, object_bucket: str, object_location: str):
        self.object_bucket = object_bucket
        self.object_location = object_location
        self.date = self._date()
        self.source_bucket = self._source_bucket()
        self.source_object_location = self._source_object_location()
        self.source_object_path_prefix = self._source_object_path_prefix()
        self.source_object_filename = self._source_object_filename()
        self.source_object_extension = self._source_object_extension()
        self.destination_bucket = self._destination_bucket()
        self.destination_path_prefix = self._destination_path_prefix()
        self.destination_object_location = self._destination_object_location()
        self.datasets = self._get_datasets()

    def _match_inbound_csv_to_dataset(
        self,
    ):
        datasets = []
        for dataset in ACTIVE_DATASETS:
            if re.match(rf"{dataset.file_match_regex}", self.source_object_filename):
                datasets.append(dataset.dataset_name)

        if len(datasets) == 0:
            raise MatchingDatasetNotFound(
                f"No matching dataset found for inbound file: {self.source_object_filename}"
            )

        if len(datasets) > 1:
            raise MultipleMatchingDatasetsFound(
                f"Multiple matching datasets found for inbound file: {self.source_object_filename}"
            )

        if len(datasets) == 1:
            print(
                f"Matching dataset {datasets[0]} found for inbound file: {self.source_object_filename}"
            )
            return datasets

    def _get_datasets(self):
        if self.source_object_extension == "xlsx":
            return None
        else:
            return self._match_inbound_csv_to_dataset()

    def _date(self) -> str:
        return datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    def _source_bucket(self) -> str:
        return self.object_bucket

    def _source_object_location(self) -> str:
        return self.object_location

    def _source_object_path_prefix(self) -> str:
        "Used for filtering objects not dropped in the proper folder"
        split = self.object_location.split("/")[:-1]
        path = "/".join(split) + "/"
        return path

    def _source_object_filename(self) -> str:
        return self.object_location.split("/")[-1]

    def _source_object_extension(self) -> str:
        split = self.source_object_filename.split(".")
        if len(split) == 1:
            return None
        return self.source_object_filename.split(".")[-1]

    def _destination_bucket(self) -> str:
        return os.environ.get(
            "EMPASSION_INGEST_BUCKET_NAME", "dev-ingest"
        )

    def _destination_path_prefix(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.source_bucket}/{self.date}"

    def _destination_object_location(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.source_bucket}/{self.date}/{self.source_object_filename}"
```

it's called and used like so:

```
class Input(BaseModel):
    object_bucket: str
    object_location: str


class Output(BaseModel):
    source_bucket: str
    source_object_location: str
    source_object_path_prefix: str
    source_object_filename: str
    source_object_extension: str
    destination_bucket: str
    destination_path_prefix: str
    destination_object_location: str
    datasets: List[str]


@http
def main(request):
    resp = Input(**request.get_json())
    file_metadata = FileMetadata(resp.object_bucket, resp.object_location)

    output = Output(
        source_bucket=file_metadata.source_bucket,
        source_object_location=file_metadata.source_object_location,
        source_object_path_prefix=file_metadata.source_object_path_prefix,
        source_object_filename=file_metadata.source_object_filename,
        source_object_extension=file_metadata.source_object_extension,
        destination_bucket=file_metadata.destination_bucket,
        destination_path_prefix=file_metadata.destination_path_prefix,
        destination_object_location=file_metadata.destination_object_location,
        datasets=file_metadata.datasets,
    )

    return json.dumps(output.model_dump()), 200
```

Comment: This is missing import statements.

Comment: To help reviewers give you better answers, we need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*.  Please add sufficient context to your question to describe the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  Also, [edit] the **title** to simply [**summarise the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Comment: sorry @TobySpeight i was unaware of that. thanks for rolling it back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Getters

You define a lot of "private" getters like `self.date = self._date()` which returns `datetime.today...`. Let's use a few `@property`s for that

```py
from pathlib import Path


class FileMetadata:
    def __init__(self, object_bucket: str, object_location: str):
        self.object_bucket = object_bucket
        self.object_location = object_location
        self.source_bucket = object_bucket

        # this has some nice convenience features
        p = Path(self.object_location)

        # like p.parent, p.name, and p.suffix
        self.source_object_path_prefix = f"{p.parent}/"
        self.source_object_filename = p.name
        self.source_object_extension = p.suffix

        self.destination_bucket = os.environ.get(
            "EMPASSION_INGEST_BUCKET_NAME", "dev-ingest"
        )

        self.datasets = self._get_datasets()

    @property
    def date(self):
        # do you care if this script runs past midnight?
        if not getattr(self, '_date', None):
            self._date = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        return self._date

    @property
    def source_object_location(self):
        return self.object_location

    @property
    def destination_path_prefix(self):
        return f"{self.source_bucket}/{self.date}"

    @property
    def destination_object_location(self):
        return (f"{self.destination_path_prefix}/{self.source_object_filename}"
        )

    def _get_datasets(self):
        if self.source_object_extension == "xlsx":
            return None
        else:
            return self._match_inbound_csv_to_dataset()
```

Now we have way fewer methods. While we're here, I've utilized `pathlib.Path` to take advantage of some convenience functions.

### Repeated regexes

It might be useful to cache repeated regexes here:

```py
class FileMetadata:
    dataset_cache = {}
 
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ~snip~

    def _match_inbound_csv_to_dataset(
        self,
    ):
        datasets = []
        for dataset in ACTIVE_DATASETS:
            name, regex = dataset.name, dataset.file_match_regex

            # pre-compile the regex
            if name not in self.dataset_cache:
                r = re.compile(regex)
                self.dataset_cache[name] = r
            else:
                r = self.dataset_cache[name]

            # use the compiled regex to match
            if r.match(self.source_object_filename):
                datasets.append(name)
```

## Testing if a list is empty

Don't test if `len(lst) == 0`, use `if lst`:

```py
        if not datasets:
            raise MatchingDatasetNotFound(
                f"No matching dataset found for inbound file: {self.source_object_filename}"
            )
```

### `self.datasets`

I don't like the naming here, since you require only one dataset to match. I might be inclined to call it `self.dataset`, but it looks like it needs to be a `list` so I'll leave it alone. Let's use some unpacking to check the length of the list:

```py
    def _match_inbound_csv_to_dataset(self):
        ~snip~
        dataset, *others = datasets

        if others:
            raise MultipleMatchingDatasetsFound(
                f"Multiple matching datasets found for inbound file: {self.source_object_filename}"
            )

        print(
            f"Matching dataset {dataset} found for inbound file: {self.source_object_filename}"
        )
        return [dataset]
```

### `cached_property`

If you are on python 3.8+ you have access to `functools.cached_property` which helps simplify the `date` property:

```py
from functools import cached_property


class FileMetadata:
    ~snip~ 

    @cached_property
    def date(self):
        return datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: this is very helpful. thank you!

Comment: For `date`, you can use a [`cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) instead of implementing caching yourself

Comment: @Brian61354270 true, totally forgot about that one

Answer (score 10):

Your class is a collection of non-mutated members and transformation methods. That's pretty good already! Nice job.

Strengthen the guarantee of immutability by using `NamedTuple` as a superclass and having a class method pseudoconstructor, something like

```
class FileMetadata(NamedTuple):
    object_bucket: str
    object_location: str
    date: datetime.date
    # ...

    @classmethod
    def from_location(
        cls,
        object_bucket: str,
        object_location: str,
    ) -> 'FileMetadata':
        return cls(
            object_bucket=object_bucket,
            object_location=object_location,
            date=cls._date(),
            # ...
        )
```

For your path manipulation, use `pathlib.Path` instead of bare strings.

Yes, use `@property` for simple transformation methods like `source_object_filename`. Here is a demonstration for `_source_object_path_prefix`:

```
@property
def _source_object_path_prefix(self) -> Path:
    """
    Used for filtering objects not dropped in the proper folder
    Given /a/b/c.foo as an object_location, returns directory /a/b
    """
    return self.object_location.parent
```

Comment: would you be able to update your answer on how you would create the `@property` methods?

Comment: @metersk See edit. I've attempted to do a 2-in-1 demo with `@property` and `pathlib`.

Comment: Hmm I might be a bit confused. Isn’t `object_location` a string? How can I call `.parent` on it?

Comment: As in my review - don't store it as a string; store it as a `pathlib.Path`

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thanks!